# What kind of encoder encodes string like this?

Tags: string, encode

I have a question about encoding/decoding strings.

Well, there is web page, where I send some data with simple php POST form.
When I open Chrome Developer Toolbar -> Network, in "Form Data" all parameters are displayed normally, except this, "uid", which is encoded ( **%25%DC%BE%60%A0W%94M** ) somehow.

[image]

When I clicked on "view URL encoded", it showed me this "**%2525%25DC%25BE%2560%25A0W%2594M**", I tried online tools such http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to get human readable string of this encoded parameter, but no luck.

Can anyone explain to me, how can I get the original value of this parameter? Not encoded, in human readable format?

Thanks a lot : )

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `%25`, for example, represents character 0x25, which is the `%` character. Clicking on "view URL encoded" gave you a double-encoded version. I don't know the significance of the particular data you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having problems with online decoders, and (seeing as its a relatively short string) why not give it a go by hand?

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

This table maps characters to their URL-encoded equivalent, just do a `Ctrl+F` of the % encoded characters and decode it yourself.

A few of the characters look wierd because they aren't English characters. `%DC` is `Ü` for example. its possible the encoders you are trying don't recognise non-english characters

Answer (score 1):

This decoder works better:

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/urlencode/Decode.aspx/

The `%25` that you see is the actual percent character `%` being encoded

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

> Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding, is a mechanism for
>   encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under
>   certain circumstances.
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> it is also used in the preparation
>   of data of the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" media type, as is
>   often used in the submission of HTML form data in HTTP requests.

Comment: Ok, I get it, that %25 is same as %, but what about other characters? Any thoughts? 
I've tried that encoder too, but it returns some strange kind of data " %ܾ`�W�M" .. what should I do ?